# TP and TQ are the two tangents to a circle with centre O so that ∠POQ = 110°

Tags: circles

If TP and TQ are the two tangents to a circle with centre O so that ∠POQ = 110°, then ∠PTQ is equal to

My attempt:

[image]

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ are $90°$ each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ OP ⊥ PT and TQ ⊥ OQ $

$ ∴∠OPT = ∠OQT = 90° $

Now, in the quadrilateral POQT, we know that the sum of the interior angles is 360°

So, $ ∠PTQ+∠POQ+∠OPT+∠OQT = 360° $

Now, by putting the respective values we get,

$ ∠PTQ +90°+110°+90° = 360° $

$ ∠PTQ = 70° $

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have upvoted it too